# Нужна ли запятая после Киев?

Tags: пунктуация

Ваш приезд в такие города, как Питер, Москва и Киев, может стать причиной....

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая здесь нужна. Это разновидность приложения, присоединенного двойным союзом "такие, как". Обособленное приложение заканчивается словом "Киев" и продолжается основная часть предложения